# Confused about strong convergence

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

If $X, X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are real random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbf{P})$, we say $X_n$ converges *almost surely* to $X$, if 
$$\mathbf{P}\Bigl[\{\omega\in\Omega : \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega) = X(\omega) \}\Bigr] = 1\, .$$

Now assume the random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ converge pointwise to some random variable $Z$. Does the following hold
$$\mathbf{P}\bigl[\{\omega \in \Omega : Z(\omega) = X(\omega)\}\bigr] = \mathbf{P}\Bigl[\{\omega\in\Omega : \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega) = X(\omega) \}\Bigr] \, ?$$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes. Except from a null set, $Z=\lim X_n =X$.